# Iterating over views in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm a Ruby on Rails noob. I work through Michael Hartl's [tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/) on Ruby on Rails. So far, I'm on chapter 3 about static pages. So far, I have `StaticPage` controller with three views: `home`, `help` and `about`. The layout for the controller goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Sample App</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do now is to add menubar, i.e. list of links to all static pages. So far, I have something like this at `<body>` tag:

```
<ul>
  <% '???'.each do |page| %>
    <li>Page!</li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I can't figure out what to put instead of `'???'` - I need an iterator of all views of a controller. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for requires more than adding static pages. You will need a database backed `model` to store dynamically created pages and a `controller` to work with the `model` actions which gives you the ability to generate `collections`.

With `collections` you can then have something like

```
<ul>
  <% '???'.each do |page| %>
    <li><%= page %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Since you are working with that tutorial, what you need to render your menubar is this

```
<ul>
  <li><%= link_to "Home", home_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, that's harder than I thought! Thanks for the answer, but can you explain how to print page title (I mean symbol `:title` that is in every view of our controller) in Embedded Ruby (`<%= page %> -> <%= page.title (???) %>`) and explain in more details the database part (or tell me where it will be in tutorial)

Comment: Digest the tutorial little by little, you'll get to the part where all these have been listed

Answer (score 0):

You can render something from the database in the controller and use it in the views. Like in the controller, I can write `@ones = Something.all` in a method called `one` and if I have a show method in the controller who shows one record from the database depending on the argument it takes, then I can add a link as below and it will take me to `something_show_path/:something_id`.

```
<% @ones.each do |one|%>
    <%= link_to "#{one}", something_show_path(@one) %>
<% end %>
```

But in this case, there is no record of the static pages you have in the database. So, if you want a syntax like that in the views, add them in an array in the controller like

`````
def whatever 
    ```rest of the code````
    @pages = ["home", "about", "help"]
end
`````

And in the view, you can write

```
<ul>
    <% @pages.each do |p| %>
        <li><%= link_to("#{p}", :controller => 'static_page', :action => "#{p}") %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

**Edit for the question in the comment**

````
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

   before_filter :load_pages, :only => [:about, :home, :help]

   ``` All your controller codes ```
    private
    def load_pages 
        @pages = ["load", "about", "help"]
    end
 end
````

So that all the methods in the `:only` list will have @pages loaded before rendering the page. You don't have to load it in each method. you can declare the method in the `ApplicationController` by writing a private before it like I did it here and just call it in any controller with the `before_filter`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add @pages to the controller? I've tried to put the declaration in `ApplicationController.initialize`, but the code in the view gives nothing. (no error, but no list items either)

Comment: There are several methods to do it. The simplest yet not so good approach is to set a global variable as you were trying to use. Don't use a `@` sign before the variable. Add a `$` sign. And you don't need to have it inside the initialize method. Just write it outside all the methods.

Comment: Like ```$post = ["about", "help"]``` Or you can define a private method to be called in the controller itself before calling each methods. Like ```before_filter :load_pages, :only => [:about, :home, :help]``` and in that function add like the variable @pages. I will update that in the answer.